# change query string url using htaccess in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to change url structure of page in wordpress

**from:**`http://example.com/page-name/?id=rd123`

**to:**`http://example.com/page-name/rd123/`

I have tried below code in .htaccess, I am getting ID if i use id numeric(123), but I am getting 404 page not found error if use id alphanumeric(rd123).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page-name/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ pagename.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

what i am missing in above code, it is in wordpress and i am not getting any perfect solution. here, page-name is template.

Comment: `pagename.php?id=rd123` or `page-name/?id=rd123` ??? Because here `-` and `/` can change the result !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page-name/(.*)/?$ page-name/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page-name/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ page-name/index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It's not a problem with alphanumeric...